# How to avoid creating new instance of FSharpFunc when calling recursive inner function?

Tags: performance, recursion, f#, inline

Sample:

```
let inline ReadState() = 

    let rec f (w : SpinWait) = 
        if (...) then
            w.SpinOnce()
            f(w)
        else
            result 

    f (new SpinWait())
```

Using ILSpy I notice that `ReadState()` create new instance of `FSharpFunc` every time it got called

```
new Memory@f222().Invoke()  // Memory@f222 implement FSharpFunc
```

How to avoid it?

If `f not inner fun` then `no instance created` but I will need another named function:

```
let rec InternalReadState(w : SpinWait) = .... 

let ReadState() = InternalReadState(new SpinWait())
```

not very beauty :(

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations / tailcalls on?

Comment: Yes, release mode, optimize + tail-calls checked, uncheck prefer 32bit

Comment: what is your motivation behind trying to remove this ?

Comment: performance of course, expect 5-7M call/sec for `ReadState()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, you've got a few alternatives, but you may not be happy with any of them.  The simplest thing would be to drop `inline` and then move the `()` argument to after the nested function:

```
let ReadState = 

    let rec f (w : SpinWait) = 
        if (...) then
            w.SpinOnce()
            f(w)
        else
            result 

    fun () -> f (new SpinWait())
```

You need to drop `inline` here because it can only be applied to syntactic functions.

Your other alternative is to create another named function, as you note.  If you're worried about polluting your scope with unneeded named functions, then there are some options for mitigating that.  You could use a signature file to only expose the `ReadState` function, or you could use the `private` modifier to make it private outside of the scope you're in:

```
module MyStuff =
    let rec private f (w:SpinWait) = ...
    let inline ReadState() = f (new SpinWait())
```

Comment: Nice, `f` and `ReadState` compiled to static members, thank you so much!